# Center all equations

Tags: equations, alignment

Is there a mode to make all the equations(only the equations) in my document, in the form ${equation}$, become centered at once?

example code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.1in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\begin{document}
blablabla1

$hv=\phi+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$

blablabla2

$hv=\phi+\frac{1}{2}m{v}_{max}^2$

more blablabla and text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\[ \]` to display a math content.

Comment: @Sigur Oh, nice. I was wanting to a mode that automatic make all centered, but, I think I rushed. Add \[ \] one by one isn't too much difficult, soooo, worth. thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments

Comment: @JouleV can I vote too? I don't know how to make that, extremely newbie here

Comment: @user188990 Not yet - you need [250 reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes). However, no worry: we will vote for you. It will be closed soon :)

Comment: @JouleV thankss

Comment: Off topic -- don't leave a blank line before a display; the vertical spacing will be wrong.  And if the paragraph continues after the display, don't leave a blank line there either.  (You might benefit from reading the `amsmath` user guide.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton even using the parskip package?

Comment: @user188990 -- I'm unable to test, but since the presence of a blank line or `\par` causes display math mode to apply the `\predisplayskip` differently than when the display is started in horizontal mode, I have serious doubts.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Understand. thxx